# Having trouble with rsnapshot via ssh (from debian laptop) of Nokia n900

Tags: ssh, rsnapshot

** edit 8/6/15 *
So the crux of my problem turned out not to be some quirkiness with the config file.  In the end it turned out I simply had multiple ssh directories in 2 different places, and was using the wrong one.  It's an embarrassing mistake to make, but live and learn, right?

I'm trying to do a backup of my Nokia N900 (a linux box smart phone) with `rsnapshot`.  For reasons I can't understand, `rsnapshot` throws up the following error:

```
rsync: Failed to exec /usr/bin/ssh -p 22 -i /home/thelemur/.ssh/id_rsa_n900: \
No such file or directory (2)
```

What's strange about this to me is that I can run the very same `ssh` command line from a bash terminal, and have no problem.  I've tried playing with the backslashes, entering the `rsnapshot` command from root, and even placing a `sudo` directly in the `rsnapshot` config file.  I've also checked my tab placement in the config file.  Does anyone know what I've been doing wrong?

Comment: "I can run the very same line from a bash terminal..."  **What command line?**  You should probably show us the config file, too.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have put this command in your cmd_ssh line, like this:

```
cmd_ssh     /usr/bin/ssh -p 22 -i /home/thelemur/.ssh/id_rsa_n900
```

then you have unfortunately tickled an interesting almost-bug in `rsnapshot`. The problem is that the `cmd_ssh` parameter takes the entire value - including spaces - as the `ssh` alternative to run, whereas what you (and previously I) would want in this scenario is shell parsing of the option.

What you need to do is either to create a little script that contains the necessary `ssh` invocation and call that, or to set up the `ssh` configuration in the `$HOME/.ssh/ssh_config`.

The former is easier; just put the following into a script such as `/home/thelemur/.ssh/ssh_with_id_rsa_n900.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ssh -p 22 -i /home/thelemur/.ssh/id_rsa_n900 "$@"
```

Then make it executable `chmod u+x /home/thelemur/.ssh/ssh_with_id_rsa_n900.sh`, and finally use that in the `rsnapshot` configuration:

```
cmd_ssh     /home/thelemur/.ssh/ssh_with_id_rsa_n900.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'll give this one a shot, and let you know how I do.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to you on this.

Comment: My problem turned out to be a simple rookie mistake, but this post was the most helpful, since it gave me a new approach which helped me understand my problem.  It also clearly explains a common and difficult to realize problem rsync users might encounter.